# How can I connect a Spring Boot API to SAP

Tags: java, spring-boot, sap

I am really new working with SAP connections and I would like to know how to connect my API to SAP using Spring Boot in a basic way.

Is there any dependency to add or just a simple code suggestion?

Any help and suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @huggo santillan follow this page https://medium.com/pacroy/running-spring-boot-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-ceede6d65106

Comment: I wonder which SAP software you are talking about... (saying "not SAP HANA" as in the original text is meaningless as SAP is a software company, there are hundreds of different software)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a spring-boot expert, but to connect to SAP ECC you have a few options:

## Connectors

SAP provides a set of different connectors to allow a communication with external systems. Those packages are supplied free of charges but with some legal limitations (see [license FAQ](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors.html#section_561121760)). You also need credentials for the SAP Support to download it

Below a couple of connectors that can be suitable to your case

### JCO connector

It is a Java library that allows you to make remote enabled functions call
See official [link](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/jco.html)

### SAP Business Connector

Another package to enable communications between SAP and external systems. Link [here](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/bc/details.html)

### .NET Connector

Same as JCO, for .NET framework

## Call a WS provided by SAP system

If SAP is already providing the service you need to call (standard or a custom developed one) you can call it as a normal web service.

If such a service does not exist or is not exposed, some activities in SAP system will be needed (creation of the service itself, endpoint configurations etc...)

## Using a middeware

You can call a service (soap/rest) through a middleware.

SAP provides its SAP Netweaver Process Orchestration, but others are available. This options is basically the same of the previous one: some work is needed in SAP system/Middleware system.